# MySql SeLinux policy permissions

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

Currently I have an apache server set up (it's running an intranet site,) and I'm a little stuck. When the user goes to the page it runs a mysql query and uses `INTO OUTFILE` to generate a pipe delimited file from that query. The problem that I am having is that SELinux is preventing mysql from writing the file to my desired directory.

The directory that I am trying to write to is either

```
/var/www/html
```

so that when its generated the user will receive a link to the file so they can download it directly from their browser.

I have tried setting the context of the directory to

```
mysqld_etc_t
mysqld_home_t
mysqld_var_t
```

and also tried,

```
var_t
```

however I'm not sure I did var_t correctly.

I have tried setting SELinux to Permissive for testing purposes, and mysql was able to write successfully to the folder, so I know that all that is standing in my way is SELinux.

I don't want to disable SeLinux nor do I want to set mysqld to run permissively. So my question then becomes what do I have to do to allow mysql access to write to that folder?
Even if someone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to write a selinux policy and then add the policy via seedit or just disable the selinux its for process security only. i.e. it prevents one process to access the memory of other.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not so easy as you expect. It is not a good idea to allow mysql to access any of httpd's types and also it is not a good idea to allow httpd to access any of mysqld's types because of security reasons.

Also changing type to is insufficient because there is no access from httpd or otherwise there is no access from mysqld.

The final point is to create a new SELinux type and grant access for both of httpd and mysqld and label a shared directory with that type. Than you can share data just in that directory between httpd and mysqld.

The explanation about controlling access in SELinux and creating own rules is on http://debian-handbook.info/browse/wheezy/sect.selinux.html